# Get project organization list in GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform

how could I print the organization label that each project belongs to ?? I can certainly get it by using

```
gcloud project list -format=csv | grep organization.
```

But I couldn’t use that command on my existing bash script that prints project name, id, zone , internal up, external ip. Idea is to tag all my current list of projects with their respective organizations. I am doing the is by bash because I’m not aware if There is a gcpoud command that gives these king of information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [cloud asset inventory](https://cloud.google.com/asset-inventory/docs/searching-resources) for this. Use this query

```
gcloud asset search-all-resources --scope=organizations/<OrganizationID> \
  --query="name://cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com/projects"
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you had in mind, but if you label all the projects manually with the label `org` for example, then you can output it with 
`gcloud projects list --format="table(projectId,name,projectNumber,labels.org)"` 
and filter with 
`gcloud projects list --filter="labels.org=<org_name>"`

Comment: thanks jabbson, please take a look at the screenshot, I am trying to get these organizations mapped to their projects. I just need gcloud command to get these.
IAM --> Labels --> Organization.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/9XxH5.png

Comment: Which "there" organizations? Organizations are not mapped to the projects, it is the other way around. Gcloud command to get what "these"?  What do the arrows represent?

Comment: `gcloud projects list --format json | grep "organization"`, this gives me project level lables which has different organizations under the main ORG. Please check the screenshot i.stack.imgur.com/9XxH5.png

Comment: This is what the first command from my answer below does, it lists the project names as well as the value of the 'org' label for said project.